# AddThis customized linkedIn and pintrest image not working

Tags: facebook, twitter, linkedin-api, addthis, pinterest

My client wants `Facebook`, `twitter`, `pintrest` and `LinkedIn` button with statastics by AddThis. but instead of using default images i want to use custom images with same functionality for AddThis.
I can manage this with Facebook and twitter icon. but with linkedin and pintrest i can not make addthis effect with custom images. i have surfed `google` but not getting proper solution.

My code is

```
 <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <div class="addthis_toolbox">

    <div class="custom_images">

    <a class="addthis_button_facebook" style="float:left;"><img src="http://192.168.1.2/wp_site/code/wp-content/themes/ofr/images/fb.png"
         border="0" alt="Like" /> </a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter"><img src="http://192.168.1.2/wp_site/code/wp-content/themes/ofr/images/twitter.png"
           border="0" alt="Tweet" /></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_linkedin"><img src="http://192.168.1.2/wp_site/code/wp-content/themes/ofr/images/email.png"
              border="0" alt="Mail" /></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit" pi:pinit:media='http://192.168.1.2/wp_site/code/wp-content/themes/ofr/images/email.png'></a>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-517656c20d974f82"></script>
```

Comment: For the Pinterest block, you're missing an image tag inside the <a> tag.  But otherwise, your code looks fine.  I can't verify your images, but when I replace them with valid images locally, the code works for me.  What isn't working for you? Images not loading or buttons not sharing to the right service?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-54d3c9035fe03473" async="async"></script>

<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook" addthis:url='Url' addthis:title='Title'></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter" addthis:url='Url' addthis:title='Title'></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_linkedin" addthis:url='Url' addthis:title='Title'></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share" addthis:url='Url' addthis:title='Title'></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_email" addthis:url='Url' addthis:title='Title'></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact" addthis:url='Url' addthis:title='Title'></a>
</div>
```

Also, I'm not sure about pintrest, but you definitely have to make sure your og tags are correct for LinkedIn. [I would refer to this page.](http://www.addthis.com/blog/2013/09/03/an-intro-to-meta-tags-how-they-work-with-smart-layers/#.VagTQflVhBc)

Comment: It would be a great idea to add some explanation so this answer could be useful for others as well.